# SQL query to return record if the price is higher and the ID is lower than previous ID and price records

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm having issues writing a SQL query to return a record when I have a dataset similar to the following:

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 32967 | 39 |
| 14675 | 40 |
| 26434 | 41 |
| 18495 | 42 |
| 19698 | 43 |
| 19090 | 44 |
| 9278 | 45 |
| 14932 | 46 |

I would like to return the id and price when the price is greater than previous price and the id is lower than previously low priced records.  So with the above data I would like to return:

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 32967 | 39 |
| 14675 | 40 |
| 9278 | 45 |

I truly appreciate the help.  I'm to the point where my brain has shut off and I'm certain I'm missing something obvious.  Know when to ask for help, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, a cumulative `min()` does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(id) over (order by price rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_min_id
      from t
     ) t
where prev_min_id is null or id < prev_min_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9ee0a56e7881a4d18a6bad748d9360c3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Gordon, I just want to say thank you for how prompt your response was!  I will go give that a shot and report back.  Thank you!

Comment: This is working very well for me Gordon....I owe you one!  Thanks again!